# PHP User Warning: 'Comparison between Long/String: 0 and "" with result (1)

Tags: php

I see the below PHP warnings on the server running PHP `8.1.2` version:-

> PHP User Warning: 'Comparison between Long/String: 0 and "" with result (1)'

This is the piece of code where it is generating the warnings:-

```php
if ($gain != 0 || $gain != '')
{
    //Do Something
}
```

The `$gain` variable is expected to be a `string` value.

I tried to reproduce the same warning using `$gain = "123.15"`, `$gain='123.15'`, `$gain=123.15`, `$gain = null` etc. but couldn't reproduce the warning.

Anyone please help me to understand what possible values of `$gain` could be generating those warnings? Thanks!

Comment: `the $gain variable is expected to be a string value`...then why are you testing whether it contains a number?

Comment: P.S. `if ($gain != 0 || $gain != '')`....this logic is screwed. It will always return true, because any given value will _always_ be either "not 0" OR "not ''). If it's 1, then it's not either of those, so it returns true. If it's 0, then it's 0, but it's still not '', so that returns true too. If it's '', then it's not 0, so it returns true. Not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: More relevant, your code seems to produce the warning, so you can probably easily check what the value of `$gain` is when it does. I tried all values I could think of, and I don't get this message. Your problem is not reproducible (by me).

Comment: @ADyson: I tried it with `$gain = null` and then it doesn't return true. See: https://3v4l.org/pa0Ut Same for `$gain = false`, see: https://3v4l.org/1NQJD

Comment: `please help me to understand what possible values of $gain could be generating those warnings`...add some logging to your code, where you write the value of `$gain` (just before the `if` runs) together with a timestamp. Then next time you get the warning, correlate the time of the warning to the time of the log, and that should help you. But as KIKO says, I can't reproduce it either, so it's a bit strange.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware good spot. Maybe that's what the OP is trying to test?! Can't see how it would be useful with any other values.

Comment: "PHP User Warning" is a user generated error ([e_user_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)), most likely created with [trigger_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php). Which means your code is generating that error/check, not regular PHP. You can probably track down where that error is being created with `grep -R 'Comparison between' *` from your project root

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? Know that php.ini settings could also influence what PHP does with code.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your response. These warnings are from production server, i couldn't just the debug statement and echo the value as a first approach, yes i understand this condition is little screwed and that's i need to fix it understanding how does it caused.

Comment: I could tagged only one user :(

Comment: In that case you can always copy the comment multiple times and tag each user. But also, anyone who is "following" the question will get notified regardless.

Comment: `i couldn't just the debug statement and echo the value as a first approach,`...If you note, I suggested logging rather than echoing. Then it doesn't interfere with usage :-)

Comment: @aynber, that's something new for me, will surely check and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @aynber, I don't see any "Comparison between" occurrence in the entire code. Could you please suggest? Is it something configurable at the server?

Comment: Start by searching for any calls to `trigger_error` then (as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php). Possibly the exact message string is either built from multiple variables, and/or taken from text stored elsewhere (e.g. in a data file, or database table, perhaps).

Comment: Make sense, need to join bits and pieces to see how these warnings are generated, it's going to be tough but I don't see any other way to proceed.

Comment: @aynber, Thanks for the hint, the error is user-generated and is reproducible when the `$gain` value is empty i.e. `$gain = ''`  (because of this conditional check: `$gain != 0`).